# rxjs: group by min time

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I have following:

```
let observable = Observable.create((observer: Observer<any>) => {
    this.observer = observer;
});
....
can fire fast in row:
observable.next('a new message');

observable
  .delay(1000)
  .subscribe((msg: any) => {
    // Not interested in msg, just in the event.
  });
```

I am not inteterested in the message at all.
Only in the fiered event. But like to group events fired fast in row.
The .delay(1000) allready delay the events but the fires every second blocks of all events. How ca i group it so the i get only one event.

Comment: Group how? Maybe `throttleTime()` or `debounceTime()` could do what you need? http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-throttleTime or http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-debounceTime

Comment: Can you explain in a marble chart what you want?

Comment: I dont know what a marble chart ist but the solution is to use .debounceTime(1000) insted of .delay(1000)

Answer (score 3):

If you want lossy calls, you can use **.debounceTime()** which will drop values emitted until the source quiets for a certain time.

The loss-less alternative is **.bufferTime()** which provides an array of all emitted values for a specific time interval.

From the documentation example[1]

```
var clicks = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'click');
var buffered = clicks.bufferTime(1000);
buffered.subscribe(x => console.log(x))
```

[1] http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-bufferTime